# Save a YouTube playlist of all videos from an uploader

Tags: video, youtube, url, playlists

The only way I know to automatically generate a playlist of all videos from an uploader is adding "&list=UL" at the end of url of any video from the uploader.

Usually I can copy a playlist into my account by entering the url of it at this website called "Copy YouTube Playlists" :
http://ctrlq.org/youtube/playlists/

But it doesn't work for playlists generated by adding "&list=UL" to the url. The website "Copy YouTube Playlists" would say : "Sorry but we could not find that playlist on YouTube. Please entire a valid YouTube Playlist URL."

Could anyone please tell me how to automatically create a playlist in my account which contains all videos from an uploader? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download all videos of a playlist without installing any software and in easy ways, then only solution is 
http://www.collectyoutube.com/?utm_source=stackexchange&utm_medium=referral

In order to download all the videos, just copy and paste the youtube video playlist video link and hit Download. It will download all the videos of the playlist. Besides it, you can also download subtitles of the video i

Answer (score 0):

Take the YouTube channel address, replace `UC` at the beginning with `UU` and add it to a playlist url. For instance, my channel address is `UCS9whElVXYORQnkABq3h-eg`, and the playlist url to all my uploaded videos is `https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUS9whElVXYORQnkABq3h-eg`.